# How to store and retrieve personal data bound to public resource that is cached

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rest, caching

Title may be confusing however I will explain what problem I am facing:

1. I am building big social portal where main content will be `Post`.
2. Each logged in user may "love" each `Post`.
3. On each portal page there will be many different posts fetched from database with specific conditions (like posts form category, posts from tag, posts from user 1, etc etc).
4. Portal is a single page app that is communicating with REST API
5. I wanted to cache api requests that fetch posts from database (/posts?CategoryId=2 etc).
6. In every place I have to mark each post if it was loved by user or not.

So far I was doing it by SQL query that checked if post was loved by requested user - but I can't do that when I want cache post requests... Is there any standard approach?

I could for example get all post ids that user loved when user login and then check each post rendered on client side if its id is there... But when user will love for example 2000 posts then it wont be fast...

I could make additional api for example GET /isPostLoved?postId=1,2,3,99,100 that would return if posts with given ids are loved by user or not... But that would be additional API request for each posts request...

Comment: Why would you cache 2000 posts? The user is probably interested in the newest 10 or 20 posts.

Comment: nope - on each page there are around 100 posts (posts are actually videos shown as video thumbnails)